# xamarin.forms GestureRecognizer on colelctionview changes background color to more than one item

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have build a collection view with a content view:

```
   <CollectionView x:Name="carouselview_categories"
                                     HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                                     ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
                                     HeightRequest="70">
                          <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                               <DataTemplate>
                                   <ContentView Margin="5,0,5,0" >
                                       <views:CV_CatsAndTags Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                                   </ContentView>                          
                                </DataTemplate>
                          </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                     </CollectionView>
```

The contentview:

```
<ContentView
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    HorizontalOptions="Start"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="InteriorCircle.Pages.ContentViews.CV_CatsAndTags">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" >
            <Frame BackgroundColor="#2C2E31" IsClippedToBounds="False" Padding="15,15,15,15" CornerRadius="12">
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                 <Label Text="{Binding title}"
                        TextColor="White"
                        FontFamily="JakartaReg"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        FontSize="16"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                 />
            </Frame>
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

I now attached a gesture recgnozier to the view to change the background color when it is clicked:

```
        void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var item = sender as Xamarin.Forms.Frame;
            var model = item.BindingContext;

            item.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#60CED3");
        }
```

But the result works buggy. If I have 6 elements in my list and click one. Another item that is currently not being rendered will have its background color changed as well. Once you scroll to it, youll see that it is also changed.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

I think it has to do that you are changing directly a property of a view and CollectionView does some kind of recycling, in order to optimize the scrolling, it just reuses the frame.

The best thing to do is tie the color to a binding to the object and that the color of the frame depends of that binding.

Another way would be changing the selection mode to "Multiple" in the CollectionView and changing the selected item color using VisualStates. [Here is how](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/selection#change-selected-item-color)

---

A small code recommendation, do not nest so many layouts

There is no need to nest everything with a ContentView

You can ommit the first one

```
                  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                       <DataTemplate>
                               <views:CV_CatsAndTags Margin="5,0,5,0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                  </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
```

You have a Frame inside a Grid inside a ViewContent Inside another Viewcontent, you can just use the Frame in the XAML

And then the contentView replace it with a Frame(also in the code behind)

```
<Frame
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="InteriorCircle.Pages.ContentViews.CV_CatsAndTags"
BackgroundColor="#2C2E31" IsClippedToBounds="False" Padding="15,15,15,15" CornerRadius="12">
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                 <Label Text="{Binding title}"
                        TextColor="White"
                        FontFamily="JakartaReg"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        FontSize="16"
                        HorizontalOptions="Start"
                 />
</Frame>
```

Comment: I guess your right. How can I stop the caching? OR: If I make this be a bindable property and change it, how can I update the UI?

Comment: First you will need a bool public property like `IsSelected` on the class that you are showing. Then you can add to the TapGesturRecognizer a parameter `<TTapGesture Recognizer CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>`  and then inside the class, your new bool property should trigger RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected)). For this, the object must inherith from [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-5.0)

Comment: Here is a [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)